# Fade out swfObject with jQuery (or any method)

Tags: jquery, fadeout, swfobject

I am using swfobect to embed a youtube video into a page. I have got event listeners that make the video hide using jQuery hide(); to get rid of the video once is it finished.

Replacing hide(); with fadeOut('slow'); does not work, though it does work when applied to another element at the same time.

Obviously this is something to do with swfobject but I don't know any more than that.

http://goo.gl/7zEwm - link to jsfiddle showing all code.

If anyone has any ideas how to make the #ytplayer1 element fade out that would be great.

Thanks in advance.
Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed changes to the html, css, and script. I forked your fiddle to here:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/4kHWj/1/)

Make sure your html is like this:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
<div id="popupVideoContainer1">You need Flash and JavaScript in order to view the video.</div>
<div id="videoStatus">status</div>
    </div>
```